# SQL Count based on Cross Product Usage

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below data which I am trying to figure out how to build a SQL query to count Customers that use *Bathroom* products AND are also using a *Kitchen* product.

**Example 1**: Jim uses Kitchen product *b* AND is using our *Bathroom* product, so I would like to show a count of 1 for product *b.*

**Example 2:** Pete uses both Kitchen products *a* and *c* AND is using our *Bathroom* product, so I would like to show a count of 1 against both *a* and *c.*

**Example 3:** Abby does not use any Kitchen products, so I do not care that she is currently using our bathroom product. I do not need any count for her.

**Desired Output:**

| Kitchen Product | Customer Count Using Bathroom Product |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 2 |

**Table Data:**

| Customer | Product_lvl_1 | Product_lvl_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abby | Bathroom | Bathroom |
| Jean | Kitchen | a |
| Jim | Bathroom | Bathroom |
| Jim | Kitchen | b |
| Joe | Bathroom | Bathroom |
| Joe | Kitchen | b |
| Pete | Bathroom | Bathroom |
| Pete | Kitchen | c |
| Pete | Kitchen | a |
| Robin | Bathroom | Bathroom |
| Robin | Kitchen | a |
| Sally | Kitchen | b |
| Tom | Bathroom | Bathroom |
| Tom | Kitchen | b |
| Tom | Kitchen | c |

**Here is the data:**

```
create table customer_prods
(
    customer varchar(30),
    product_lvl_1 varchar(30),
    product_lvl_2 varchar(30),
    revenue number
)

INSERT INTO customer_prods
    (customer,product_lvl_1,product_lvl_2,revenue)
VALUES
    ('Abby','Bathroom','Bathroom',1),
    ('Jean','Kitchen','a',6),
    ('Jim','Bathroom','Bathroom',6),
    ('Jim','Kitchen','b',8),
    ('Joe','Bathroom','Bathroom',7),
    ('Joe','Kitchen','b',6),
    ('Pete','Bathroom','Bathroom',9),
    ('Pete','Kitchen','c',2),
    ('Pete','Kitchen','a',8),
    ('Robin','Bathroom','Bathroom',7),
    ('Robin','Kitchen','a',9),
    ('Sally','Kitchen','b',6),
    ('Tom','Bathroom','Bathroom',8),
    ('Tom','Kitchen','b',7),
    ('Tom','Kitchen','c',8);
```

Comment: Please replace images with formatted text. See [why should I not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (as text we can copy/paste and execute, **NOT** images); an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output (again, as text formatted using markdown).

Comment: Can't understand how did you get 67% in the fist row. Please elaborate. I see 3 out of 3... 100%, right?

Comment: Why is the `product_1_count` for `a` `2`? All the `a` rows have `kitchen` in `product 1` so it is not clear why the count is 2 and not 1 (i.e. you want to `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`) or 3 (i.e. you just want to count the rows).

Comment: Why does your `product_level_2` column not include `Bathroom`? That is listed in the `product_level_2` column in the data-set alongside the `a`, `b` and `c` values?

Comment: There are 3 customers who use product 'a', but of those 3 only 2 use the 'Bathroom' product.  This has been my challenge.

Comment: @MT0 - As for your question why Bathroom is repeated in both level 1 and 2.  we use product hierarchies.  Some do not have descriptions at the lowest level, so they repeat the value of the last level.

Comment: As said before, please provide a proper [MRE] which include a decent explanation of the problem including features such as this as to why some rows should be excluded or what the hierarchical nature of the data means for the logic for how to generate the output. No-one on StackOverflow has any domain knowledge of your data so your problem does not make sense and needs explaining.

Comment: @MTO - thanks for the guidance.  I have tried to add more clarity of what I need and an example dataset